# How can I speed up this SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, performance, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that contains user_id, time, inHour and outHour like this

[image]

I want to group with user_id and get max time with related fields. In the picture below you can see what I want as result.

[image]

My query works well. But i want to improve speed, because it works slow for large data. Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  foo.user_id,
  foo.time,
  foo.inHour,
  foo.outHour
FROM
(
    SELECT
        MAX(time) AS time,
        user_id
    FROM 
        foo
    GROUP BY user_id
) AS t1
INNER JOIN foo ON (t1.user_id = foo.user_id AND t1.time = foo.time);
```

I need to drastically reduce the query time. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are your tables indexed ?

Comment: Did you create index to user_id/time in both tables?

Comment: There is only one table @Roy

Comment: Make a temporary table with the max time of each user (and create index in both tables)

Comment: @Roy - making a temp table will only make it slower (in this situation).

Answer (score 0):

Groupwise-max?

You will need a composite index.  Your existing query would benefit from

```
INDEX(user, time)  -- in this order!
```

My blog provides even faster techniques:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max